# PHP if condition changed by content of block... what?

Tags: php, post, if-statement

I have this code, on a page that *is* processing posts

```
// some stuff
$isPost = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST';

if ($isPost) {
   // logic, including some redirects, but no echoing
}
else {
     echo 'not post';
}
```

The thing is, that just echos "not post", but if I add an echo inside the if:

```
// some stuff
$isPost = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST';

if ($isPost) {
    echo 'post'; //or var_dump, print_r

   // logic, including some redirects, but no echoing
}
else {
     echo 'not post';
}
```

it prints `post`, and then the redirect errors since I've already echoed some stuff to stdout.

There is no way that that is right.

This might be a server configuration error, because this does not happen on my dev box. Any ideas where even to *look* for solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it is redirecting to itself. The first time is a POST, the `if` is true, it redirects to itself as GET and then the if is false.

Either that or you aren't editing the file you think you are, etc. There's no black magic in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I had eliminated all my redirects as being a possible cause, but yeah indeed one of them was potentially cyclic.